# How can I put object values ​in url in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to modify the value in the object. However, modified routing does not work properly.

```
#routes
root 'freelancers#index'

get 'new' => 'freelancers#new'
post 'category' => 'freelancers#category'  

get 'video' => 'freelancers#video'
get 'video/show/:id' => 'freelancers#video_show'
get 'video/new' => 'freelancers#video_new'
post 'video/create' => 'freelancers#video_create'
get 'video/:id/edit' => 'freelancers#video_edit'
patch 'video/show/:id/update' => 'freelancers#video_update'

get 'design' => 'freelancers#design'
```

Form code:

```
<%= form_for(@video, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => @video.id, :url => '/video/show/:id/update' }, method: :patch ) do |f| %>
```

i expect the output of /video/show/3/update
but the actual output is video.3

Comment: Not sure I got your question, but maybe try to change `:url => '/video/show/:id/update'` to `:url => "/video/show/#{@video.id}/update"`?

Comment: @ĐônNguyễn thanks, Your proposal was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fast way:**

Change this line:

```
patch 'video/show/:id/update' => 'freelancers#video_update'
```

To:

```
patch 'video/show/:id/update' => 'freelancers#video_update', as: :update_video
```

This will create `update_video_path` as named helper in your application. Then you will be able to use it:

```
<%= form_for(@video, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => @video.id, :url => update_video_path(@video) }, method: :patch ) do |f| %>
```

You can check [the documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes) for more information.

**Better way:**

You might want to refactor your routes and controllers. It is a good practice when your controller covers one resource. In your case it seems that you need at least two controllers: `FreelancersController` and `VideosController`, and `videos` resources should be nested inside `freelancers`.

For example, it might look like this:

```
root 'freelancers#index'

resources :freelancers, only: [:index, :new] do
  collection do
    get :design
    post :category

    resources :videos, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show, :edit, :update]
  end
end
```

I left `design` and `category` in the example as is, but probably these routes also need the separate controllers.

This way is better, because:

1. Routes become more understandable and more supportable
2. Your controllers are responsible for only one resource each
3. You get a bunch of [path and URL helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) without additional work
4. Your application follows the conventions

Of course, if you need to customize application URLs, Rails provides you the way, but in most cases following the convention is better.

You can find more information in [the documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

Comment: keyword 'as' mean like nickname?

Comment: @dj-Yang Kind of. It allows to set the name for the route. It's described [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes). Also it allows you to [override the default naming for the named routes helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers).